# SQL Server: how to select sub-query column in main query

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a query to select particular day-time for a office.

```
select 
    a.sat_date, 
    b.officeid 
from  
    OfficeHours a 
where 
    sat_date = '9:30 AM'
    and officeik in (select OfficeIK from office where officeid = 50000) b
```

I need to select the sub-query column `officeid` in main query. Above query throws a `syntax error.`

Thanks for the help.

Comment: not defined alias `a` and what's the error you are getting?

Comment: I think b.officied -> b.officeid

Comment: I have edited the questions. thanks for pointing out

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't use `officied` column from subquery not only because that subquery select list doesn't contain this column, but also bu the reason it is in where condition, not in some join/apply.

Instead you can join that subquery and use it columns like this:

```
select 
    a.sat_date,
    b.officied 
from OfficeHours as a
    inner join (select * from office where officeid = 50000) as b on b.officeik = a.officeik
where a.sat_date = '9:30 AM'
```

or (even simplier and more natural):

```
select 
    a.sat_date,
    b.officied 
from OfficeHours as a
    inner join office as b on b.officeik = a.officeik
where 
    a.sat_date = '9:30 AM'
    and b.officeid = 50000
```

Comment: thanks for the solution. but clear on the point "subquery select list doesn't contain this column". I am selecting all the columns in the subquery table

Comment: @bmsqldev your subquery is `(select OfficeIK from office...` and not `(select OfficeIK, officeid from office`, so even if it was in join - you can't use column you're not included into select list since it will not be present in query result

Answer (score 1):

You can use inner join:

```
select a.sat_date ,b.officied
 from OfficeHours a inner join office b on(a.officeik=b.OfficeIK)
  where a.sat_date = '9:30 AM' and b.officeid=50000
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `INNER JOIN`, if you want to use sub-query, you can try this:

```
select a.sat_date, 50000 AS officeid
from OfficeHours a
where sat_date = '9:30 AM'
   and officeik in
   (select OfficeIK from office where officeid = 50000)
```